# Zeppelin interpreter: Not able to share interpreter accross notebooks

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Recently I upgraded my zeppelin from `0.8.1` to `0.9.0-preview` (Also upgraded spark from 2.2 to 3.0,1).
Here I am not able to execute notebooks parallelly(by same user or different user). First executed notebook submit job on spark keeps running on other hand all other notebooks shows as waiting.

Even after first notbook is successfully completed, other notbooks not able to execute.

I was able run multiple notebook simultaneously in previous version.

Setting in zeppelin intrpreter is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You get only one session when you share your session globally. That means every executed paragraph is queued and processed sequentially as shown in the picture below:
[image: Shared interpreter]

Depending on your working environment you should change your setting to `per note` or to per `per user` (in case of a multiuser environment) and  `scoped` or `isolated` mode.

Below is an overview from the official [documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/interpreter/interpreter_binding_mode.html) of the advantages and disadvantages of the `shared`, `isolated`, and `scoped` mode from a notebook perspective:
[image: PerNote Overview]

Comment: Paragraph should run (running also) sequentially, but notbook can run parallelly? the behaviour is perfectly working in `zeppelin-0.8.*` but not in `zeppelin-0.9.0-preview`

Comment: @HiteshGhuge Notebooks can run in parallel when you change the settings to `per note` and `scoped` or `isolated`.

Comment: in that case interpreter will created per note?

Comment: @HiteshGhuge in `isolated` it will be the interpreter and in `scoped` it will be a session. Please read the table of my answer, it contains all the answers.